# What is the maximum allowed files open?

Tags: files, programming

Is 1048577 the limit of open files in Ubuntu? If I try the following code it works.

However, if I change the value to 1048578 the setrlimit function will return the code 1 and errno will be set to 1 as well.

```
int l;
struct rlimit rl;

rl.rlim_cur = 1048577;
rl.rlim_max = 1048577;

l = setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl);

if(l != 0){
    errx(1, "setrlimit returned result %d", errno);
}
```

I am running it as root and compiling with GCC 4.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've hit the kernel maximum (NR_OPEN), see

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/nr_open
```

Comment: So if I change this file and reboot it I got a new maximum?

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't work this simple.

Comment: I think you would have to recompile the kernel ;( Can you tell me why you need to have so many open files per process?

Comment: It's the way my application works, I am changing it to have at maximum 65536 files or maybe less. As far as I tested 65536 is ok.